# Infinite Loop on API GET Requests

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm relatively new to working with APIs and I'm looking to fetch data from an API using a GET request and this code is causing an infinite loop of GET requests. What I'm ultimately looking to accomplish is to access the data I'm receiving in res.data so I can pull information from the object that's being returned in the API response (using something like res.data.name which is currently prompting an error saying res is not defined which I believe could be due to a scope issue).

```
  const Podcast=()=>{


    const[show,setShow]=useState([])
    const[bestPodcasts,setBestPodcasts]=useState([])
    const [genre,setGenre]=useState('')
    const[data,setData]=useState({})

    client.fetchBestPodcasts(
        {  genre_id: '91',
    page: 2,
    region: 'us',
    safe_mode: 0,}
    )
.then((res) => {
    setData(res.data)
    // Get response json data here
    console.log(res.data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `useEffect` hook, this shall call your API only once/initially:

```
const Podcast = () => {

    const [show, setShow] = useState([])
    const [bestPodcasts, setBestPodcasts] = useState([])
    const [genre, setGenre] = useState('')
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        apiCall()
    }, []);

    const apiCall = () => {
        const data = {
            genre_id: '91',
            page: 2,
            region: 'us',
            safe_mode: 0
        }
        client.fetchBestPodcasts(data)
            .then(res => setData(res.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
}
```